# Rails 4 create associations in class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This works perfectly fine:

```
User.first.social_profiles.create!
```

On the other hand, this creates the `social_profile` but does not create the association between the two:

```
class SocialProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.create_google( auth_info )
        # if where(provider: auth_info["provider"], uid: auth_info["uid"]).empty?
            create! do |google|
                google.provider = auth_info["provider"]
                google.uid = auth_info["uid"]
                google.image_url = auth_info["info"]["image"]
                google.email = auth_info["info"]["email"]
                google.access_key = auth_info["credentials"]["token"]
                google.refresh_token = auth_info["credentials"]["refresh_token"]
                google.expires_at = Time.at(auth_info["credentials"]["expires_at"])
                google.expires = auth_info["credentials"]["expires"]

            end
        # else
            # where(provider: auth_info[:provider], uid: auth_info[:uid]).first
        # end
     end

end
```

Console:

```
2.1.2 :102 > User.first.social_profiles.create_google( ...the auth hash ...)
```

What's the problem here? How can I fix it?

This does work though

```
p = User.first.social_profiles.create_google(...the auth hash ...)
User.first.social_profiles << p
```

Answer (score 0):

The User.first instance does not get carried into the SocialProfile.create_google method, and therefore the create! method wouldn't have the user instance available.
You can assign it yourself by passing it in:

```
class SocialProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_google( user, auth_info )
    create! do |google|
      google.user_id = user.id,
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

And calling it with

```
SocialProfile.create_google( User.first, auth_info )
```

Alternatively, consider having the create_google_profile method in User, so that you can

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def create_google_profile( auth_info )
    self.social_profiles.create(
      provider: auth_info["provider"],
      ...
    )
  end
end
```

and calling it with

```
User.first.create_google_profile( auth_info )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I realize it doesn't get carried over but I don't know why. It seems like this is unique to `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations because a `has_many` does not cause this problem?

Comment: I've always assumed that class methods wont have the association. Never did explore further. 
Not really relevant, but out of curiosity, does your the social_profile has_many users ?